# NestJS CORS doesn't work - what do I have to do?

Tags: cors, nestjs

No matter how I try to activate CORS in my NestJS application, I am not able to get it running. I tried almost every possibility I could find on the internet. Why is this a problem at so many projects? What causes the issue?

I tried:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {cors: true});

app.enableCors();

app.use(cors());

const options: any = {cors: '*'} // cors: true // cors: ['http://localhost:4200'] // ...
app.enableCors(options);

app.use(cors(options));

@Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200') // on a specific method

...
```

I always get the Error "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present in the requested resource.
[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x10cr.png)

I would be very grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Try adding `app.options('*', cors())` and see the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: now it works, but to be honest, I have no idea why..
anyway, thanks four your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that it isn't working?

I have something like this in a recent NestJS project, running v7.2.0.

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)
 
  // ... 

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    app.enableCors()
  } else {
    app.enableCors({
      origin: config.get('server.origin'),
      // methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
      // credentials: false,
      // ...
    })
    logger.log(`Accepting requests from origin "${config.get('server.origin')}"`)
  }
```

This is covered here in the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security

Other than that, I'd make sure that you're using Nest correctly in your controllers. If you're doing anything to play with the response or change headers you could be stepping on something??

Comment: It is not working because my frontend application is logging an error (see screenshot / error message).

Thanks, but also the version you mentioned doesn't work. I am getting the same error.

From my point of view everything is set up correctly on the backend as I am able to request the resources via Postman e.g. I have no idea what causes the issues here. But in other threads I read about the same but I finally couldn't find a solution that works for me.

Comment: now it works, but to be honest, I have no idea why..
anyway, thanks four your help

Comment: Weird, too bad you couldn't nail it down to anything in particular! Glad you got it working, cheers!